# Remove edits from pictures

Tags: photoshop, image, editing, image-editing

How do we remove edits from a picture, specific to remove a black bar which was added on top via MS Paint?

Comment: Nice try, but that's most likely not possible. What's the file format?

Comment: Then it's not possible, sorry.

Comment: Depends on the content of the image. If you show us the image I might be more able to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it's a JPEG file. You can only remove a black part if the file has layers: whatever is underneath the black part needs to be stored in the file as well. For JPEG files that's not the case: the black part has simply replaced the previous content so it's no longer part of the file. So it's not possible in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

its simple open the image in Photoshop
select the area which you want to keep...with the help of `marquee tool`.
then crop the whole image{`go to top bar then image>crop`} and save...and you are done